# document/literal or an RPC/encoded interface

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, rpc

So i wanted to know, which interface should a company use? a document/literal or an RPC/encoded interface and why? I am really confused as I have read about the advantages and disadvantages of both but can't understand which one would be better and why

Answer (score 0):

WS basic profile prefer literal style. So use because it would provide better interoperability.
http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html

Also another good explanation is in:
[/encoded and /literal support in JAX-WS/CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234514/encoded-and-literal-support-in-jax-ws-cxf)

Also read
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/index.html